# Как хранятся в памяти литералы?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

Как хранятся в памяти литералы?

```
int main() {
  5;
  1.;
  "";
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

С абстрактной точки зрения "в памяти" в языке С++ хранятся только *lvalues*. Из приведенных вами литералов только строковый литерал `""` является *lvalue*, т.е. только он хранится в памяти.

Остальные литералы не являются *lvalue* и формально положения в памяти не имеют.

---

Фактически же целочисленные литералы обычно "встраиваются" в тот контекст, в котором они использованы. Они могут встроиться непосредственно в сгенерированную машинную команду (то есть стать частью кода, а не данных программы), а могут вообще неузнаваемо трансформироваться или бесследно раствориться в этом контексте: умножение на 8 может замениться на сдвиг влево на 3 разряда, а присваивание переменной значения 0 может замениться на машинную инструкцию обнуления.

Что произойдет с литералом с плавающей точкой — зависит от способностей компилятора и особенностей подлежащей машинной платформы. На платформе *x86* в общем случае плавающий литерал действительно будет храниться в памяти, т.е. для его хранения будет заведена внутренняя переменная. В то же время компилятор вправе распознавать "особенные" плавающие константы (`0.0`, `1.0` и т.д.) и реализовывать их неявным образом. Но, еще раз, в любом случае на уровне языка плавающий литерал положения в памяти не имеет.

Comment: Едва ли строковой литерал является `lvalue`. Это неименованный участок памяти ведь. Вы в этом уверены?

Comment: @megorit: Стандарты С и С++ открытым текстом говорят, что строковые литералы являются lvalue. "Участок памяти"  - это уже фактически определение lvalue. Lvalue никак не связано с именованностью.

Comment: Я не против. Но временные объекты тоже на стеке лежат ведь, а они rvalue (xvalue или prvalue). Возможно, тут больше уместен термин glvalue.

Comment: @megorit: Во-первых, спецификация языка не говорит, где лежат временные объекты. Во-вторых, *объекты* не могут быть lvalue или rvalue или еще что-то. Категории значений применим только к *выражениям*, а не к объектам. Временный объект запросто может быть lvalue, если вы доступаетесь к нему через lvalue-выражение. Привяжите к временному объекту ссылку - но вот вам готов lvalue доступ к временному объекту.

Answer (score 13):

Арифметические литералы не хранятся в памяти, а встраиваются в объектный код.
Строковые литералы хранятся обычно в отдельном пуле литералов, так как они имеют статическую длительность используемой памяти. Одинаковые строковые литералы могут храниться как один литерал, либо как отдельные литералы в зависимости от опций компилятора.

Поэтому данное выражение в if предложении

```
if ( "A" == "A" ) { /* ... */ }
```

может иметь значение как `true`, если эти два литерала хранятся как один литерал, то есть имеют один и тот же адрес, так и `false`, если компилятор хранит каждый из этих литералов в отдельном участке памяти.

Что касается этой программы

```
int main() {
  5;
  1.;
  "";
}
```

то так как данные предложения выражений не имеют побочных эффектов, то для них может вообще не генерироваться никакой объектный код.

Answer (score 6):

Да никак... Пока они не использованы - для инициализации переменной, например, или там в вызове функции. И то они могут не храниться - например, какое-нибудь `a >>= 2` просто превратится в машинную команду, в которой просто указано непосредственное значение 2, без всякого хранения.

Comment: а если переменная уже была проинициализирована и мы присваиваем ей новый литерал? значение же должно скопироваться

Comment: Это уже второй вопрос :) Который, вообще говоря, зависит от компилятора, архитектуры etc. Например, если что-то типа `const char * s = "Hello, Dolly!";` - то строка будет где-то в памяти, а в переменную пойдет указатель. Если что-то типа `int i = 345;` - то просто может быть ассемблерная команда `mov eax, 345`. Дело в том, что даже переменные могут храниться не в памяти, а в регистрах, например... Поэтому абсолютно точный ответ дать, пожалуй, не получится.