# Где хранятся временные объекты?

Tags: c++, c

Где хранятся временные объекты-константы? Знаю, что у констант, таких что не объявленных, то адреса нет, кроме строковых литералов, например:

```
printf("%d", 5); // Где хранится константа? В регистре процессора? Адреса у нее нет.
int value = 10; // Аналогично

printf("%s", "I am just a string"); // Адрес у строки есть, но где она хранится? На стеке?
```

Если можно, то простым языком) Спасибо!

Comment: регистры процессора слишком мимолетны. да, константа в них конечно попадет в момент выполнения. А до этого она есть только в машинном коде инструкции, помещающей ее в регистр, например какого нибудь `mov eax, 5` (если это x86)

Comment: А вот `int value = 10;` это не константа, а переменная, имеющая начальное значение 10. В зависимости от того что это за переменная, она может быть в сегменте данных программы, внутри исполнимого файла, может помещаться в стек в момент выполнения (опять же из машинного кода самой инструкции) или вообще использоваться непосредственно в инструкции где идет дальнейшая работа с ней

Comment: Что касается строки в printf - она будет в сегменте данных (который находиться отдельно внутри исполнимого файла)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/618499/394322

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Стандарты C/C++ описывают только как ведут себя те или иные конструкции этих языков. Что происходит у программы "под капотом" в них не написано, поэтому зависит от компилятора. Сюда входит:

- Что помещается в регистры (или куда-то еще), а что нет.
- Существование стека и кучи. В стандарте написано только как долго существуют объекты, созданные тем или иным образом. Где они при этом находятся - не написано.
  (Хотя это занудство... На практике `new` создает объекты в куче, локальные переменные создаются в стеке, и т. д.)

---

Если хочется чего-то менее формального и более практичного, почитайте про [сегменты объектных файлов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file#Segmentation).

Можете засунуть ваш код в [дизассемблер](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxEJNIAHVAsLraewyaCnt5qdFY29kZOLm5KKqG0DATMxAT%2BxqacisqYqr5JKQThdo7OrorJqemBWQqVRdYlUWWSAJSKqAbEyBwA5FIAzNbIhlgA1OIDOsh1%2BKiT2OIADACCyyvWBGNGzNYQreviAOyyq2PnY%2B7Em1QQUpJSAKzo96RjjwcD0mMA9D8TABEluIAJwDcRA8TSbgQ4HSR6AzjiAAcjwhSORwMh0ixcIBsKhyPRKIeAIxSLJKIAYoC4WtsYtsfjKciKRjSXDcVDmeyCTjJjSCSDJIiUVz4XzwdiiSy2STiZi%2BQi%2BVSFeLGRiAGxKhVy1l8jVivnAgaCyEg8UwlnitGy42i5EDWncnXY5VM13sgB06wuY02YwAbmwDJgJgMAWNOCbvn9nRa%2BczOXzZAzJXyZRijomDYczhcrjc7pIHpJHgpXhMSwBJMbMIxjPgGOp1sZ1a6ie6fWP/IWWtWelGcB1O3UK0kY9V8%2Blw5HOiV2lkTlE6N45hnzqVwq1w91wxl4%2B0K22T43r2fjscs1Wm%2BNJqFLB16jlQ210nWmw5HAG9dqsEC9I8vSkKYvRLMBqAATochyG2nTdGGgycMBBAAeBrTtAA1iAjySF6nBHI8SyaksILIpqAxLKiWT/r03DAaB4GkJBvTAQoIBLKQqFgb%2BpBwLAMCICgqBGO4eDsGQFAQGgoniWUIwiMA0ZLJxVDiQQzjsRADhocBDjWCkACeAHIaQMlGFoBAAPK0Kwxk8aQWA7KI7C6Y5eDELkaiBpg7EOZgAAeuQGBpbmbMobmsHgDjEEZehYCZKHXEYiXtDQ9BMGwHCcAM/DlMIogoDBMhCNF7GQO0qDuAkfkALSzJMAISDIciSMwYy1QA6mwrAdZ1gUELFHXuJg6AiGoyC1c4xAkAobE5HkGgQOY1SZKQ5jFJE0RBF4Ph0KtO0hL4m2lC4tQLQkBRVPoGSCHEXn5PUJ3NGdFSFAdtRPY0W1lJw7QKPBPRcH%2BAFASBbksQF5G1Zq3BjApohRksXrI4%2BEC4IQJBVgMWRjHoskSdjbR48V0gobpGGkAgmDMFgLj7KQ2HcI8KPcEskhHLDAwDI8OMgiCQgAfRpApUR4MOSxbEcVxFN8YJEBIJ0BDuCF5CUDJYkSeUo2Y696WMCwrnRqQADusXuKlguAQxEMAYMIom4QCBjFDmow3DCPAEjKMo%2BTPGU9TtNlAztHC6LnGMRBAFS5x3HoVhIDcEcXrIpI3BghaOWaiCnCPFbAw2xL0cy/7IO9JIhdMZLJfx6QPnEN4GjcEAA%3D) (результат будет зависеть от выбора компилятора и флажков для него).

У меня получилось вот что:

- Константы `5` и `10` стали частью инструкций `mov` ().

  ```
  mov esi, 5
  ...
  mov dword ptr [rbp - 4], 10
  ```
- `value` - на стеке.
- Про строковые литералы по выводу дизассемблера не очень понятно. Думаю правильно будет сказать, что они находятся "в сегменте данных" (см. ссылку про сегменты выше). Явно не в стеке - объекты на стеке уничтожаются при выходе из функции, а строковые литералы существуют все время работы программы.

Comment: Что касается "взятия адреса константы" - то вы получаете адрес не константы, а ее копии - аргумента функции `address`, т.е. ее локальной переменной, находящейся в общем случае в стеке (и то необязательно; тут уж куда оптимизатор запихнет), и то только потому, что вы запросили ее адрес...

Comment: А можно ли считать `42` константой? Это ведь просто литерал, а само выражение имеет категорию категорию значения prvalue.

Comment: @isnullxbh В C++ это литерал. В C это называется константой (слово литерал там вроде используется только для строковых литералов и для compound literals).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, понял, спасибо!

Comment: @Harry Сначала хотел возвразить, потом вспомнил про temporary materialization и засомневался... Лучше вообще уберу эту часть ответа.